# How to to filter the array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When I input in the input, the ul only show the `li` which include my input. For example, if I am inputting the"Ad", then only show the "Add some todos" li. And if I give up input, the ul will go back, and all the Li will show again.  How to realize It?

It is my code below.

```
<body>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ctr1">
    <input ng-model='newTodo' type="text" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && addTodo()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in fillArray">
            <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
            <button ng-click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>

    var app = angular.module("app",[]);
    var contrl = app.controller('ctr1',['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.todos = [{text:"Add some todos"}];
        $scope.newTodo = '';
        $scope.addTodo = function () {
            var text = this.newTodo.trim();
            if(text){
                this.todos.push(
                        {text:text}
                );
                this.newTodo= '';
            }
        };
        $scope.removeTodo = function (index) {
            this.todos.splice(index,1);
        };

        $scope.fillArray =$scope.todos.filter(function (item) {
            return (item.text.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf($scope.newTodo) > -1);});
    }]);

</script>
</body>
```

**How to get the fillArray? ** My code is wrong.

Comment: Create a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) OR [**Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that someone can provide you any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="ctr1">
    <input ng-model='newTodo' type="text" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && addTodo()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter : newTodo">
            <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
            <button ng-click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>

    var app = angular.module("app",[]);
    var contrl = app.controller('ctr1',['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.todos = [{text:"Add some todos"}];
        $scope.newTodo = '';
        $scope.addTodo = function () {
            var text = this.newTodo.trim();
            if(text){
                this.todos.push(
                        {text:text}
                );
                this.newTodo= '';
            }
        };
        $scope.removeTodo = function (index) {
            this.todos.splice(index,1);
        };


    }]);

</script>
</body>
```